# How to deal Leaflet map control checkboxes?

Tags: leaflet, mapcontrol

I add some geojson layers to the map control once a layer is loaded and the control can show all the layer names. But I notice that all the checkboxes are unchecked by default. So that once I click the control to uncollapse it, all the layers disappear. And I have to check them one by one to display them again.

The code is like:

```
ctrl = L.control.layers([aBaseLayer]); ctrl.addOverlay(aGeoJsonLayer, 'ageojsonlayer');
```

Then I can control the aGeoJsonLayer, but unlike the aBaseLayer, the aGeoJsonLayer is not checked by default in the control panel. So every time after the layer is loaded, when I click the control, the layer will be gone until I check it in the control panel.  Any way to fix this?

Comment: how about providing some functioning code (or a jsfiddle) to demonstrate the issue

Comment: @Kelso The code is like: ctrl = L.control.layers([aBaseLayer]); ctrl.addOverlay(aGeoJsonLayer, 'ageojsonlayer'); Then I can control the aGeoJsonLayer, but unlike the aBaseLayer, the aGeoJsonLayer is not checked by default in the control panel. So every time after the layer is loaded, when I click the control, the layer will be gone until I check it in the control panel.

Comment: Please add and format the code into your question. I said functioning code or jsfiddle to make it easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like

`L.control.layers([aBaseLayer], [aGeoJsonLayer]).addTo(map);`

Although you may want to add your layer as a geojson layer:
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson

Answer (score 1):

Your code only creates a control layer and does not add your base layer or overlay to the map. So if your `aBaseLayer` and `aGeoJsonLayer` are not on the map when you create the control layer, the checkboxes will not be selected.